# Fetch JSON data from a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I had a link where I get the data in JSON format.

sample data:-

```
[{"Code":"1","Headline":"Rescale","SubHeadline":"bla bla bla","Author":"abc","StoryDateTime":"2012-1-1 12:12:12"}]
```

Now I want to show only 10 records. When I reach near the bottom of page while scrolling it automatically add another 10 records, total 20 messages.( like facebook,twitter) and repeat the process again and again till the data ends.

Could anyone help me how to do it with jquery please?

Comment: What have you tried...? There are many examples online for this sort of "infinite scrolling"

Comment: i need full code with the includes files..i mean complete working code..i had tried many codes but not able to do the needful

Comment: Yeah... this isn't the place for that. Pay someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is pagination i think... You need to have some mechanism in your server end to support pagination first... jQuery alone will not help you to achieve this...

Comment: i already had the pagination on my server side..i had done this by giving URL arguments..like:- http://www.abcfdfds.com?p=1 then p=2 and so on.

Comment: great that is half the problem solved now all you need to do is append the new data to the old one using $('<element>').append()

Comment: yes i want to append the data to the existing div.. and i already used the $('<element>').append()...but first of that i need to retereive the next data means from p=2...from a link and then i need to append

Comment: get the data you need to append using an ajax call in the success function append the new data to the existing div

Comment: i am done with all the possible codes that i can write or search...can u plz explain me with code...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think this is what you want

```
$.Ajax({

url: 'abcfdfds.com',
data: {p: 2},

success: function(response){//Iam assuming this response is an array
var i=0;
for(i in response){
$('div you want to append to').append('<div>' + response[i] + '</div>');

}

}

})
```

Hope this helps out

Comment: <div id="messages">
    hello
    <div id="newMessages">
    </div>
</div>


<input type="button" value="Fetch more messages" id="btnFetchMessages" />




<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var lastFetchedMessage = 0;
$('#btnFetchMessages').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{"lastId":'+lastFetchedMesasge+'"}',
        success: newMessagesReceived
});

</script>